# Relation between these sparse matrices

Tags: sparse-matrices

I have two sparse matrices output from two different programs which should (in theory) represent the same problem. Here are plots of the sparse matrices where coloured squares represent non zero elements and the white squares represent zero elements. Both matrices are symmetric and positive definite.

Is there an obvious relation I am missing which relates these two matrices, or does it require a deeper analysis than just visual inspection? Their structure is so similar, and I just can't see the operation that causes the reversal of the "leaf" like structures of the matrix. Apologies if this is the wrong exchange to post this in; if it is I will gladly move to a more suitable one.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like certain blocks are getting flipped across their "anti-diagonal".